# Centering logo in middle of menu

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting to place the logo (which will be just title of business - Soul Mix) in middle of menu items. With similar spacing like example website below.

[image]

Would like it to be responsive across screen sizes - so that logo name stays when on smaller screen. Menu goes into a hamburger menu anyway.

This is the code I used to already center the menu, not sure if it is right but any help would be really appreciated.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 990px){
.header--middle-left .header__inline-menu {
margin-left: auto;
min-width: 1200px !important;
text-align: center !important;
width: 100% !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "help" site. It's a question and answer site. It works best if you try to solve a problem yourself, then if you get stuck, ask a question and include enough code for us to replicate the problem.